# A regular expression with a pattern to exclude, but the pattern itself contains a substring we want to include

Tags: python, regex

For string: `.test[?(@.foo=="bazz")].boo`, using Python I want to get matches on this string based on `.`, `[?`, `]`, but ignore on `@.`.

I've managed to figure out how to match the pattern for all splits, but can't seem to figure out the ignore rule.

`\[\?\(|\.|]`

My best attempt at the ignore rule as of now:
`^((?!@\.).)*$|\[\?\(|\.|]`

Expected results where highlighted substrings are matches:
`.`test`[?`(@.foo=="bazz")]`.`boo

Comment: apologies, updated with tool/language and expected results

Comment: You might use use a negative lookbehind? `\[\?|\]|(?<!@)\.` https://regex101.com/r/psNPke/1

Comment: That works, thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Your pattern `^((?!@\.).)*$|\[\?\(|\.|]` uses 4 alternatives, where this part   `^((?!@\.).)*$` matches a line that does not contain `@.`

If you want to match a dot that is not preceded with an `@` char, you can use a simplified pattern using 3 alternatives:

```
\[\?|\]|(?<!@)\.
```

- `\[\?` Match `[?`
- `|` Or
- `]` Match a `]` char
- `|` Or
- `(?<!@)\.` Match a dot, asserting that it is not preceded with an `@` char using a negative lookbehind

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SVKJIG/1).